# Are Gravitrons still hypothetical?

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

With the dectection of gravitational waves, can it be assumed that gravity works in the same way as the other fields? If so, isn’t the gravitron a proven part of QFT? Because the wikipedia page says its “hypothetical”

Comment: 'hypothetical' in this case means 'not been observed directly or implicitly'

Comment: Gravitational waves aren't the same as gravitons